# arrange the elements in the sorted list so that all the redundant elements are at left/right side of the list

Tags: python, list

Is there a better way to solve this problem than this one?
def rendered(arr):

```
single_elements = []  
double_elements = []  

for i in xrange(len(arr)-1):  
    if arr[i] == arr[i+1] or arr[i] == arr[i-1]:  
        double_elements.append(arr[i])  
    else:  
        single_elements.append(arr[i])

if arr[-1] == double_elements[-1]:
    double_elements.append(arr[-1])
else: 
    single_elements.append(arr[-1])

return single_elements+double_elements
```

arr = [1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9]

'''output arr = [1,2,4,5,6,9,3,3,3,7,7,7,7,8,8,8]'''

print rendered(arr)

Comment: By better, do you mean more computationally efficient, or fewer lines of code?

Comment: Computationally efficient

Comment: So, all repeated items are always going to be consecutive?

Comment: Yes, Ashwini as they are in sorted order.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about optimizing code, rather than fixing problem. It belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is the most efficient, you can make it a bit more efficient with a couple of changes using enumerate and not repeatedly indexing, it knocks about 15 percent off the runtime using python 2 and 25 percent using python 3:

```
single_elements = []
double_elements = []
for i, ele in enumerate(arr[:-1], 1):
    if ele == arr[i] or ele == arr[i-2]:
        double_elements.append(ele)
    else:
        single_elements.append(ele)
ele = arr[-1]
if ele == double_elements[-1]:
    double_elements.append(ele)
else:
    single_elements.append(ele)
single_elements.extend(double_elements)
```

Or if you want fewer lines:

```
sin_ele = []
dbl_ele = []
for i, ele in enumerate(arr[:-1], 1):
    dbl_ele.append(ele) if ele == arr[i] or ele == arr[i-2] else sin_ele.append(ele)
ele = arr[-1]
dbl_ele.append(ele) if dbl_ele and ele == dbl_ele[-1] else sin_ele.append(ele)
sin_ele.extend(dbl_ele)
```

Some timings and to cover array of one element and an empty array:

```
def sort_dups(arr):
    if len(arr) < 2:
        return arr
    sin_ele = []
    dbl_ele = []
    for i, ele in enumerate(arr[:-1], 1):
        dbl_ele.append(ele) if ele == arr[i] or ele == arr[i - 2] else sin_ele.append(ele)
    ele = arr[-1]
    dbl_ele.append(ele) if dbl_ele and ele == dbl_ele[-1] else sin_ele.append(ele)
    sin_ele.extend(dbl_ele)
    return sin_ele


In [38]: timeit sort_dups(arr)
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.69 µs per loop

In [39]: timeit f(arr)
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.05 µs per loop

In [40]: %%timeit
repeatedElements = []
[num for (i, num) in enumerate(arr[:-1]) if not
      (arr[i] == arr[i+1] or arr[i] == arr[i-1]) or
       repeatedElements.append(num)] + repeatedElements   ....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.38 µs per loop
```

Empty and single element lists:

```
In [74]: sort_dups([1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5])
Out[74]: [1, 3, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5]

In [75]: sort_dups([1, 1, 1, 1, 2])
Out[75]: [2, 1, 1, 1, 1]

In [76]: sort_dups([])
Out[76]: []    

In [77]: sort_dups([0])
Out[77]: [0]
```

On slightly larger input:

```
In [59]: arr = [1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,12,12,12,14,15,15,15,19,20]

In [60]: timeit f(arr)
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.2 µs per loop

In [61]: timeit sort_dups(arr)
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.81 µs per loop

In [71]: arr+= [None]

In [72]: %%timeit                                                          
repeatedElements = []
[num for (i, num) in enumerate(arr[:-1]) if not
      (arr[i] == arr[i+1] or arr[i] == arr[i-1]) or
       repeatedElements.append(num)] + repeatedElements
   ....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.1 µs per loop

In [93]: %%timeit
a, b = [], []
>>> for i, x in enumerate(arr):
      (b if (x in arr[i-1:i+2:2] if i > 0 else x in arr[1:2]) else a).append(x)
   ....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 14 µs per loop


In [110]:  arr = [1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,12,12,12,14,15,15,15,19,20]

In [111]: timeit reorderSequence(arr)
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.85 µs per loop

In [112]: timeit sort_dups(arr)
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.78 µs per loop

In [110]:  arr = [1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,12,12,12,14,15,15,15,19,20]

In [119]: timeit cython_sort_dups(arr)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.38 µs per loop
```

Comment: is it possible to do in without using 2 empty list memory? Let'we s say want to make minimum use of memory as well

Comment: You could use itertools.chain instead of extending the list and just iterate over that.

Comment: The fewer lines doesn't work. I made a solution that works for empty lists, lists of 1 element and everything else that also doesn't use any builtins

Comment: Great well explained answer but you should add my enumerate solution to your timings to see how it works out

Comment: @jamylak, yep, the Op'd code would also fail for that case but I added an `if dbl_ele` to catch it, the function covers the empty and single element cases. i added your enumerate also.

Comment: @Padraic This is nice work. If you decide to test my new algorithms as well, I assure you I'll stay around for the results. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it nicely in one line but I think it's best to keep it `O(N)`

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> arr = [1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9]
>>> a, b = [], []
>>> for k, g in groupby(arr):
        group = list(g)
        (a if len(group)<2 else b).extend(group)


>>> print a + b
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8]
```

Comment: See my new answer for a response to your original comment. It's almost a one-liner, at least in spirit.

Comment: jamylak, is it possible to do it without using built in functions?

Comment: @PrashantKumar yes i did that

Answer (score 0):

How's this? Let me know if it needs further explanation.

```
arr = [1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9]

repeatedElements = [i for i in arr if arr.count(i) > 1]
newList = [i for i in arr if i not in repeatedElements] + repeatedElements

print newList

>>> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, @jamylak. I raise you.

```
arr = [1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9]

arr +=  [None]
repeatedElements = []
print [num for (i, num) in enumerate(arr[:-1]) if not 
      (arr[i] == arr[i+1] or arr[i] == arr[i-1]) or
       repeatedElements.append(num)] + repeatedElements
```

I tested this with time.clock() all the way to 10*, 100*, 1000* arr. It comes out a little faster than yours at very high numbers (otherwise significantly faster at smaller amounts), at least on my machine.

***In fact***, it comes out faster than the OP's as well. Game, set, match.

Comment: well my code runs faster than yours so I guess game, set, match to me then ;)

Comment: @ Padraic: Yeah, I noticed that afterwards. I was hoping _you_ wouldn't ;)

Comment: @Padraic: Actually, it's weird. I was re-testing some code and both seem to be on par; It could just be the version I'm using though (2.7), as one or the other comes out on top half the time. I don't know why these variations exist. But, it seems to me that the differences in this case must be very, very small. Perhaps you were referring to its efficiency in Python 3?

Comment: @Eithos Before I was only talking about runtime complexity, when you had an O(N^2) solution which should generally be avoided. Yeah your code will be faster in raw speed I was just trying to find a neat solution using builtins such as `groupby`. If I was to go without those I'd do something similar to this without any builtins

Comment: @Eithos I now made a raw Python solution just for speed, see how that goes in your timings

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> arr = [1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9]
>>> a, b = [], []
>>> for i, x in enumerate(arr):
      (b if (x in arr[i-1:i+2:2] if i > 0 else x in arr[1:2]) else a).append(x)

>>> print a + b
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8]
```

@Eithos I raise you again

Some tests:

```
def f(arr):
  a, b = [], []
  for i, x in enumerate(arr):
    (b if (x in arr[i-1:i+2:2] if i > 0 else x in arr[1:2]) else a).append(x)
  return a + b

>>> f([1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5])
[1, 3, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5]
>>> f([1, 1, 1, 1, 2])
[2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> f([])
[]
>>> f([0])
[0]
>>> f([9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15])
[9, 11, 13, 14, 10, 10, 12, 12, 15, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

(Okay, I know this is highly unusual: Three separate answers. But to me... this seems warranted.)

#### Edit(1): Added Version A2 (increased optimization) >>> See tests below

#### Edit(2): Added Version A3 (extreme optimization) >>> See tests below

Just when all of you thought this was over and done with... I've come to say: ***Well it ain't***.

I raise *all of you* (@jamylak, @Padraic Cunningham, @Prashant Kumar). I challenge anyone to come up with a faster algorithm. If this happens, I will happily admit defeat and move on with my life. Until then...

#### Algorithm

I realized I was too hung up on making the perfect, fewest lines of code ever (partly because of jamylak, whose last algorithm really... wowed me. I had never thought to use ternary operators in that way. So, awesome.).

Initially, I came up with a modified version of my second answer because I wanted to quickly outdo jamylak with the least amount of effort and it seemed the way to do it. But, it was really getting kind of hacky and unclear, so it wasn't ideal. You wouldn't want a colleague to have to understand what went wrong in an algorithm that starts looking like down below..

#### Version 1

```
#...This

def version1Func(arr):

    arr +=  [None]
    repeatedElements = []
    return [num for (i, num) in enumerate(arr[:-1]) if not
        (arr[i] == arr[i+1] or arr[i] == arr[i-1]) or
        repeatedElements.append(num)] + repeatedElements
```

#### Version 2

```
# ...became this

def version2Func(arr):

    arr +=  [None]
    repeatedSet = set([])
    repeatedElements = []
    return [num for (i, num) in enumerate(arr[:-1]) if (
        repeatedElements.append(num) if num in repeatedSet else (
        repeatedSet.add(num) or repeatedElements.append(num)) if (
        num in (arr[i+1], arr[i-1])) else True
    )] + repeatedElements

# See? This becomes difficult to understand for all but those intimately 
# familiar with the abuse and hacks that are employed here. Still, it's fairly
# effective and, hopefully, if ever used, shouldn't cause any bugs afaik.
```

Both are pretty fast.

During testing (with version **2.6.4**, *not 2.7* as I said ealier. My mistake), the first one was faster than both jamylak's and Padraic's with a small data set. As the data increased, this difference became smaller and smaller. The difference was small enough that Python 3 (or other confouding factors) might give another algorithm the edge (as it's shown on Padraic's tests that his is a bit faster).

The second version is slightly slower with very small data sets, like <=50 elements. As this increases, the difference becomes rather noticeable as it really begins to shine comparatively **(*1)**. In a way, it's already a good candidate for fastest algorithm here, as generally we tend to be more concerned with large datasets when deciding that time complexity is an issue worth tackling.

But... moving on; the following algorithm/s are the fastest I've made, yielding in the best case scenario almost twice the speed as `Version 1`.

**(*1)** : *I noticed later that this was no longer the case when Padraic's algorithm was placed inside a function. It got much faster. Now, both Padraic's and `Version 2` seem on par once again.*

#### Version A1

```
def reorderSequence(seq):

    seqLength = len(seq)
    seqSetLength = len(set(seq))

    if seqSetLength != seqLength and seqLength >= 3:

        indexLength = seqLength - 1
        index = 0
        newList = []
        repeatedList = []
        repeatedNum = 0
        currentItem = 0

        while True:

            if index >= indexLength:
                lastItem = seq[indexLength]
                if lastItem != repeatedList[-1]:
                    newList.append(lastItem)
                return newList + repeatedList

            baseIndex = index
            baseNum = seq[index]

            while True:

                # Checks if the next number in the list is the same and
                # keeps resetting the while loop (with `continue`) until 
                # this condition is no longer True.
                nextItem = seq[index+1]
                if baseNum == nextItem:
                    repeatedNum = nextItem
                    index+=1
                    if index < indexLength:
                        continue
                    else:
                        index+=1
                        break

                # If the previous condition failed, this `if block` will
                # confirm that the current number is a repeat of the last
                # one and set the baseNum to the next number; it will repeat
                # the while loop (with `continue`) because of the possibility
                # that with the next number begins a new series of redundant
                # elements, thereby keeping the collection growing before
                # finally adding it to the 'repeatedList'. But if the next
                # number isn't the beginning of a new series...

                currentItem = seq[index]
                if currentItem == repeatedNum:
                    baseNum = nextItem
                    index+=1
                    if index < indexLength:
                        continue
                    else:
                        break

                else:
                    # .. it will append it to this newList, break
                    # to the outer-While...
                    newList.append(currentItem)
                break

            # ...and, at this point, it will slice the sequence according
            # to the outer-While's baseIndex and inner-While's updated index
            # and extend the repeatedList.
            if baseIndex != index:
                repeatedList.extend(seq[baseIndex:index])

            index+=1
    else:
        return seq
```

#### Version A2 - Edit(1) >>> Optimized

```
def reorderSequence(seq):

    seqLength = len(seq)

    if seqLength >= 3:

        indexLength = seqLength - 1
        index = 0
        baseIndex = index
        newList = []
        repeatedList = []
        baseNum = seq[index]
        nextNum = seq[index+1]
        repeated = True if baseNum == nextNum else False

        while True:

            if index >= indexLength:
                return newList + repeatedList

            while repeated:

                if baseNum == nextNum:
                    index+=1
                    if index < indexLength:
                        nextNum = seq[index+1]
                        continue

                index+=1
                if index < indexLength:
                    baseNum = nextNum
                    nextNum = seq[index+1]
                    if baseNum == nextNum:
                        continue
                    else:
                        repeated = False
                else:
                    if baseNum != nextNum:
                        repeated = False

                repeatedList.extend(seq[baseIndex:index])
                baseIndex = index
                break

            while not repeated:

                if baseNum != nextNum:
                    baseNum = nextNum
                    index+=1
                    if index < indexLength:
                        nextNum = seq[index+1]
                        continue
                    else:
                        index+=1

                else:
                    repeated = True

                newList.extend(seq[baseIndex:index])
                baseIndex = index
                break

    else:
        return seq
```

---

#### Version A3 - Edit(2) >>> Extremely optimized!

```
def reorderSequence(seq):

    sliceIndex = baseIndex = index = 0
    newList = []
    baseNum = seq[index]
    nextNum = seq[index+1]
    repeated = True if baseNum == nextNum else False

    try:

        while True:

            while repeated:

                if baseNum == nextNum:
                    index+=1
                    nextNum = seq[index+1]
                    continue

                index+=1
                baseNum = nextNum
                nextNum = seq[index+1]
                if baseNum == nextNum:
                    continue
                else:
                    repeated = False

                newList.extend(seq[baseIndex:index])
                baseIndex = index
                break

            while not repeated:

                if baseNum != nextNum:
                    baseNum = nextNum
                    index+=1
                    nextNum = seq[index+1]
                    continue
                else:
                    repeated = True

                newList[sliceIndex:sliceIndex] = seq[baseIndex:index]
                sliceIndex += index - baseIndex
                baseIndex = index
                break

    except IndexError:

        if repeated:

            if seq[-1] == seq[-2]:
                newList.extend(seq[baseIndex:index+1])

            if seq[-1] != seq[-2]:
                newList[sliceIndex] = seq[-1]
                newList.extend(seq[baseIndex:index])

        if not repeated:
            newList[sliceIndex:sliceIndex] = seq[baseIndex:index+1]

        return newList
```

---

As it's readily apparent, at this point I stopped caring about wanting to make the code elegant, short, etc. Elegance is fun, but sometimes to get the maximum juice elegance must be sacrificed. And, given the OP noted that what he cared about was efficiency, fewer lines or no shouldn't count.

#### Other Answers (For referemce)

```
# jamylak's:
def f(arr):
    a, b = [], []
    for i, x in enumerate(arr):
        (b if (x in arr[i-1:i+2:2] if i > 0 else x in arr[1:2]) else a).append(x)
    return a + b

# Padraic's:
def sort_dups(arr):
    if len(arr) < 2:
        return arr
    sin_ele = []
    dbl_ele = []
    for i, ele in enumerate(arr[:-1], 1):
        dbl_ele.append(ele) if ele == arr[i] or ele == arr[i - 2] else sin_ele.append(ele)
    ele = arr[-1]
    dbl_ele.append(ele) if dbl_ele and ele == dbl_ele[-1] else sin_ele.append(ele)
    sin_ele.extend(dbl_ele)
    return sin_ele
```

#### The results (Test 1)

```
# Using this as argument..
arr = sorted([1,2,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,12,12,12,14,15,15,15,19,20] * x) 
# In this case, x will be 10000 or 100

# ..and time.clock() as timer:

# jamylak's:
>>> 0.134921406994  +- 0.001     # 10000*
>>> 0.00127404297442             # 100*

# Padraic's:
>>> 0.0626158414828 +- 0.001     # 10000*
>>> 0.000532060143703            # 100*

# Mine - Version 1
>>> 0.0728380523271 +- 0.002     # 10000*
>>> 0.000671155257454            # 100*

# Mine - Version 2
>>> 0.0612159302306 +- 0.001     # 10000*
>>> 0.000565767241821            # 100*

# Mine - Version A1
>>> 0.0519618384449 +- 0.001     # 10000*
>>> 0.000506459816019            # 100*
```

#### The results (Test 2) - Edit(1)

```
# Using the following argument

arr = sorted([1,2,41,52,6,57,7,7,71,8,82,83,9,1244,132,1221,14,15,15,1523,19,20] * 10000 
+ [1,2,2,4,5,42,23,7,1,55,21,23,34,24,26,27,6,31,32,33,61,62,70])

# Padraic's:
0.0614181728193

# Mine - Version A2
0.0403025958732
```

#### The results (Test 3) - Edit(2)

```
# Using same argument as Test 2

# Mine - Version A3
0.0338009659857
```

After doing these tests, I realized something very important. Something I believe I'd already learned about a while ago, but forgotten.

*All of these* got a significant speed boost when used inside of functions. It seems the playing field was leveled quite a bit. In fact, I'd say it's been leveled all around. Before posting this, I was still running my `Version A1` algorithm inside a function and comparing it with Padraic's old one declared globally, so I thought I had a much bigger advantage until I started re-testing each one. According to my data I still come out ahead, although not as much as I had thought.

With respect to the speed boosts experienced inside of functions vs how narrower the gap became between it and my list comps: I imagine it possibly having to do with how list comps optimize very efficiently on their own, while algorithms declared locally (inside a function) perform similar optimizations.

As Lambeau says in 'Good Will Hunting': 
*"So, let this be said: the gauntlet has been thrown down, but [I] have answered, and answered, with vigor."*

So, what do you say, @Prashant Kumar? Is this more *computationally efficient* of an answer? :)

**Note:** Of course, I welcome anyone (Padraic?) to perform their own tests to see how it runs on their individual machine, Python version, etc.

*It would be also nice if the python version is indicated along with the results. It can help elucidate differences in speed.*

#### Edit 1:

My conclusion is `Version A2` is probably the fastest I'm going get it to run. There's always room for minor tweaks, but it's doubtful it'll get any significant boost IMO. I do have another version that, with the huge datasets presented here as arguments, can muster up an additional 0.002 seconds. Unfortunately, it is slightly (and, I mean, very slightly) slower at the start. So, it didn't seem worth it trading off slight loss in speed with smallish datasets for slight gain when used with mega-sized arguments.

***To the OP:*** I suggest you try some of these algorithms out, so you can give a verdict. I'm also just very curious to see if anyone can reproduce some of the results I've been getting vs @Padraic 's. On that note, I'd also be curious to find out if possibly this may have to do with differences between time.clock and timeit?

#### Edit 2:

Okay. I think I've exhausted every avenue of optimization here. And, ***it uses just one list rather than two***, which is also closer to the OP's goals (he/she was interested in seeing if this could be pulled off without creating additional, empty lists)

Comment: @Ethios, sorry to say on python2.7 your code is actually much slower than mine

Comment: @Padraic That's kind of surprising. It runs blazingly fast here, no exaggeration. It's okay though. I'm actually trying to optimize it further. I'll report back if I'm successful. By the way, does that include `Version 2`?

Comment: @Ethios, I added a cython compiled function result, have a look at that ;)

Comment: @ Padraic: I'm not familiar with Cython. Would that still be considered fairplay, though? Could the OP easily integrate that with the rest of his/her code? In your testing, did you also test larger datasets rather than looping the same call numerous times? This could be relevant, actually, because my function at the beginning performs a bunch of initialization; but, realistically, it would operate over larger datasets rather than one small one 100,000 times, if that is indeed what's happening. If that's not what's going on, please excuse my ignorance over the timeit module.. =P

Comment: I tested against 1000000 element lists also and the difference was still a similar ratio

Comment: @ Padraic Interesting. I'll get back to you on this soon (I hope). All I can say for now, is.. damn.

Comment: lol no worries, I will add another optimised version when I get a chance